# Hide absolute pseudo-element within a table

Tags: css, html-table, pseudo-element, absolute

I have a price table in which I cannot access its content, I can only modify it via CSS.

The original table has the original price and the discount price together in the same cell, only differentiated by the strikethrough of the first figure. Something like that:

> <strike>2,50</strike>2,13

I have managed to separate them by applying a different style to the offer price subclass and making a divider line applying a `:before` pseudo-element, using the `|` character and `position:absolute` for display parameters.
It works perfectly.

Tables usually have a maximum of 20-25 rows. For spacing reasons, they have a `max-height` with a vertical scroll bar to see the hidden rows in case of extensive content. In these cases, and due to the `position:absolute` of the `:before` element of the second figure, the divider line remains visible below the end of the table.

I have tried several changes without any solution. Changing the position to `relative` overrides several of the pseudo-element's display options. Any alternative?

```css
table {border-collapse: collapse;
width: fit-content;
margin: 4rem auto 3rem;
max-height: 205px;
overflow-y: auto;
display: block;
border-top: 2px solid #35D0CD;
border-bottom: 2px solid #35D0CD;
}

th {background:black; color:white; position: sticky; top:0;}

td {border: 2px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #35D0CD;
padding: 0 2rem; 
text-align:center;
}

bdi {color:blue; text-decoration: line-through;
}

span {padding-left:4rem; color:red}

span:before {content: "|";
    margin-left: -2rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: #35D0CD;
    line-height: 0%;
    position: absolute;
    transform: scale(0.2, 1);
  margin-top: 0.65rem;}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
<tr><th>Price</th></tr>
<tr><td><bdi>2,50</bdi><span>2,13</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><bdi>2,50</bdi><span>2,13</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><bdi>2,50</bdi><span>2,13</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><bdi>2,50</bdi><span>2,13</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><bdi>2,50</bdi><span>2,13</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><bdi>2,50</bdi><span>2,13</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><bdi>2,50</bdi><span>2,13</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><bdi>2,50</bdi><span>2,13</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><bdi>2,50</bdi><span>2,13</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><bdi>2,50</bdi><span>2,13</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><bdi>2,50</bdi><span>2,13</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><bdi>2,50</bdi><span>2,13</span></td></tr>
  

  </table>
  
</div>
```

Comment: `transform: translate(0);` on the table ? Not really sure how everything should be setup but if you want to limit an absolutely positioned element without changing the position of the parent for create a stacking context with transform is the simplest

Comment: just noticed `display: block;` on a table, You're not meant to change the display of a table, if you don't want to use a table use something else, Also there a lot of things wrong with your approach, If you could explain the end result of you're after a lot more clearer, you'll have a better change at getting a much more robust answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

You were correct in that the `|` was exposed because of `absolute` but it probably wouldn't be an issue if the `line-height` wasn't `0` because of that all of the `|` was pushed out vertically and it's font-size was twice the size of the default `font-size`

### Major Changes

- Removed `absolute`
- Each `<td>` with the exception of the first `<td>` is a flex container
- All `<bdi>`, `<span>`, and `<span>::before` are `inline-block`s
- Changed `line-height: 0` to `0.65` on `<span>::before`
- Adjusted `<span>::before` `padding-bottom` to `0.5ch` to close the gap on top.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  display: block;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 4rem auto 3rem;
  max-height: 162px;
  border-top: 2px solid #35D0CD;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #35D0CD;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

td {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #35D0CD;
  text-align: center;
}

bdi {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4.25ch;
  padding-top: 0.15ch;
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: line-through;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 4rem;
  color: red;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
}

span:before {
  content: "|";
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 2.5ch;
  padding-bottom: 0.5ch;
  font-size: 1.45rem;
  line-height: 0.65;
  color: #35D0CD;
}

tr:first-of-type td {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
<tr><td>Price</td></tr>
<tr><td><bdi>2,50</bdi><span>2,13</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><bdi>2,50</bdi><span>2,13</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><bdi>2,50</bdi><span>2,13</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><bdi>2,50</bdi><span>2,13</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><bdi>2,50</bdi><span>2,13</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><bdi>2,50</bdi><span>2,13</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><bdi>2,50</bdi><span>2,13</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><bdi>2,50</bdi><span>2,13</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><bdi>2,50</bdi><span>2,13</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><bdi>2,50</bdi><span>2,13</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><bdi>2,50</bdi><span>2,13</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><bdi>2,50</bdi><span>2,13</span></td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```