# Static pseudo-element within a cell

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72414913/5765312).

The pseudo-element bar line is displayed correctly when the figures contain the same amount of numbers but fails when the figures are different, for example in prices without decimals.

Does it have a solution?

```css
table {border-collapse: collapse;
width: fit-content;
margin: 4rem auto 3rem;
max-height: 205px;
overflow-y: auto;
display: block;
border-top: 2px solid #35D0CD;
border-bottom: 2px solid #35D0CD;
}

th {background:black; color:white; position: sticky; top:0;}

td {border: 2px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #35D0CD;
padding: 0 2rem; 
text-align:center;
}

bdi {color:blue; text-decoration: line-through;
}

span {color:red;}

bdi:after {content: "|";
margin: 0 1.75rem;
font-size: 1.5rem;
color: #35D0CD;
line-height: 0;
display: inline-block;
transform: scale(0.7, 1.4);}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
<tr><th>Price</th></tr>
<tr><td><bdi>2,50 €</bdi><span>2,13 €</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><bdi>2,20 €</bdi><span>2 €</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><bdi>2,50 €</bdi><span>2,13 €</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><bdi>2,50 €</bdi><span>2,13 €</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><bdi>22,50 €</bdi><span>21,13 €</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><bdi>2,50 €</bdi><span>2,13 €</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><bdi>2,50 €</bdi><span>2,13 €</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><bdi>200,50 €</bdi><span>180,13 €</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><bdi>2,50 €</bdi><span>2,13 €</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><bdi>2,50 €</bdi><span>2,13 €</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><bdi>22,50 €</bdi><span>21,13 €</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><bdi>2,50 €</bdi><span>2,13 €</span></td></tr>
  

  </table>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Made some changes to make it simpler and more reliable.
I sued `box-sizing: border-box;` to make sizes, padding and borders easier (ie: `width: 200px` will mean 200px no matter how big the padding and borders).

Then I made the `td` full-size (no padding, and width 100%), so it's children are easier to manipulate.

I made the span and bdi both inline-blocks with a 50% width, the text-align center is applied to them and not their parent.

I was then able to remove the `:after` and simply set a border-right on the bdi

```css
table, th, td, bdi, span {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

table {
  display: block;
  margin: 4rem auto 3rem;
  width: fit-content;
  max-height: 205px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 2px solid #35d0cd;
  border-bottom: none;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

th, td {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #35d0cd;
}

th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

td {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

bdi, span {
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 1em;
}

bdi {
  border-right: solid 2px #35d0cd;
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
<tr>
  <th>Price</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><bdi>2,50</bdi><span>2,13</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><bdi>2,20</bdi><span>2</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><bdi>2,50</bdi><span>2,13</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><bdi>2,50</bdi><span>2,13</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><bdi>2,50</bdi><span>21,13</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><bdi>2,50</bdi><span>2</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><bdi>2,50</bdi><span>2,13</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><bdi>200,50</bdi><span>180,13</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><bdi>2,50</bdi><span>2,13</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><bdi>2,50</bdi><span>2,13</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><bdi>22,50</bdi><span>21,13</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><bdi>2,50</bdi><span>2,13</span></td>
</tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks good. I already try it, but it doesn't work when adding the currency symbol [codepen](https://codepen.io/danielillo/pen/BaxwJrw)

Comment: It still works but introduces a line break, you can probably get away with it with `white-space: nowrap;`